# How to generate a vector with ones at a certain place?

Tags: julia

I have a vector with ascending numbers like (2,3,6,10). Now I need to generate a second vector, where all entries in the called items are 1 and all others are 0, so (0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1).

My attempt was:

## Original array

A = [2, 3, 6, 10]

## Create a new array of zeros with the maximum value of A

B = zeros(Int, maximum(A))

## Set the elements at the indices specified in A to 1

B[A] .= 1

The problem is this leads to a four-dimensional vector of ones instead of a 10-dimensional vector of ones and zeroes. The only other idea I have would be a for-loop which I would like to avoid

Comment: Why do you not want to use a for-loop? (see: [Why are loops not slow in Julia?](https://discourse.julialang.org/t/why-are-loops-not-slow-in-julia/63205))

Comment: Note that `maximum(A)` can probably be replaced by `A[end]`

Answer (score 5):

I think you've already solved this. The broadcasting operation does what you wanted, but *returns* something else.

```
julia> A = [2, 3, 6];

julia> B = zeros(Int, maximum(A));

julia> B[A] .= 1
3-element view(::Vector{Int64}, [2, 3, 6]) with eltype Int64:
 1
 1
 1

julia> B
6-element Vector{Int64}:
 0
 1
 1
 0
 0
 1
```